# Panoramic view creation from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, panoramas

I have a iPhone app requirement to create a 3D panaromic view. Users can take photos from their phone and convert it to panoramic view.

what is the good way to do this ? any libraries available for this?

Help is highly appreciable,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use PanoramaGL Library.Its very good library and very easy to integrate.
You can find it on,

https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/downloads/list